# Factory contract that can verify its children?

Tags: contract-design

It's possible to create a Factory-type Contract that can spit out other contracts:

```
contract Greeter {
  string greeting;
  address public creator;

  function Greeter(string _greeting) {
    creator = msg.sender;
    greeting = _greeting;
  }

  function greet() constant returns (string) {
    return greeting;
  }
}

contract GreeterFactory {
    function makeGreeter(string greeting) returns (address) {
        return new Greeter(greeting);
    }

    function verify(address child) returns (bool) {
      Greeter child = Greeter(child);
      // Do something amazing here...
    }
}
```

But how to verify that a Greeter at a given address is one that came from a trusted GreeterFactory? In other words, how to complete that `verify()` function on the parent Factory?

Eve could create a contract with a static `creator` property that imitates a known GreeterFactory fairly easily:

```
contract BadGreeter {
  address public creator;

  function BadGreeter() {
    creator = 0x1010101010; // Address of a known GreeterFactory contract
  }

  function greet() constant returns (string) {
    return "Trust me...";
  }
}
```

A user could easily look at the blockchain to grab the bytecode for a contract and see the difference between BadGreeter and Greeter. But how could we build it so a separate contract could do it (via a call to a `verify(address)` method of some sort that's trustless)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the address of all created contracts in a mapping. To validate a contract - any contract - just check it against that array.

```
contract GreeterFactory {

    mapping (address => bool) created;

    function makeGreeter(string greeting) returns (address) {
        var g = new Greeter(greeting);
        created[g] = true;
        return g;
    }

    function verify(address greeter) returns (bool) {
        return created[greeter];
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't see the other answer. So basically this is only good if you need to verify from within a contract. If the validation can be done before the actual tx then obviously do that instead. This costs extra gas and storage. Sorry, just wanted to be clear.

Comment: In the function `makeGreeter(string greeting) returns (address)` is it possible to return more data than simply the address?

For example, in the constructor of `Greeter(string greeting)` could you `return (string greeting)` to the Factory then save it in a mapping in the original GreeterFactory?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best approach is for the factory contract to create a child, verify its length, store it in some variable, and then check code equivalance.

Checking code equality of two addresses in serpent:

```
def check_code_equality(a:address, b:address):
    asz = ~extcodesize(a)
    acode = string(asz)
    ~extcodecopy(a, acode, 0, asz)
    bsz = ~extcodesize(b)
    bcode = string(bsz)
    ~extcodecopy(b, bcode, 0, bsz)
    return sha3(acode:str) == sha3(bcode:str)
```